# Change page content with media queries (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I have a wordpress site with info in the right sidebar, and this info is different on each page. In the main content I have a info block that say; "For more info look to the right", this info is altso different on each page. I want this info block to change with @media in CSS, so when you're on a mobile, it will say; "Look down" and not "Look right".

I've tried to do this with a wordpress plugin (Whistles), and shortcodes in the main content. But the problem is.. It's not me who's going to maintain the website, and I need this to be easy to use!

I have been thinking about using 'p class="mobile"' and 'p class="desktop"' in the page editor, but I doubt the person who's going to be in charge of the site would like nor understand it (the one who's going to be in charge of the site might be new to wordpress and will probably have no experience with coding).

Anyone know about a wordpress plugin for this? or an easy way to do this without coding?

Please help! I have about 100 pages, and I don't want 200 Whistles to make this work!!!

Comment: You can create two elements with different content and show them depending on viewport resolution  (with help of media queries).

Comment: go to appearance -> editor, there you will see different files, edit the appropriate file for the sidebar or whatever, add `p class="mobile"` or the other in that file at once and every page will be affected, now you wouldn't have to write the code on every page by page editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with media queries that change the `content` css property on a `span` tag. You simply set the breakpoint of the media query to the screen width the moves the side-bar. *You may even be able to work this into a plugin (I'm not a wordpress expert).*

```css
.side-bar-position:after {
  content: "on the right";
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .side-bar-position:after {
    content: "below";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  See block <span class="side-bar-position"></span>.
</p>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/L68n0jfq/2/)**